# String 'null' vs NULL keyword SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a question about NULL in database. From my previous knowledge, I can recall my mentor telling me that if the database is indexed and we put NULL keyword in  a field then indexing doesnt remain in effect whenever a search is conducted on database and the search is sequential which affects performance significantly (if I am wrong on this concept please correct it). I am working with database currently (DB2) and I notice string 'NULL' instead of keyword NULL. I have tried searching data with string 'NULL' and then same data with NULL and results are different.

1. I wanted to know the difference between the String 'null' vs NULL
   keyword in SQL (DB2)?
2. is one better than the other?
3. Does string 'NULL' affect indexing, this goes back to the concept i mentioned
       above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know the difference between the String 'null' vs NULL keyword in SQL (DB2)?

'NULL' is not the NULL, its a string with a value 'NULL'. Whereas NULL signifies the absence of a value. So if you write a condition like

```
where column = null    //output will be unknown 
where column = 'null'  //output will contain all rows that have the string 'null'
```

> is one better than the other?

It depends on your requirement. However when you are trying to store NULL then it is not the same as 'NULL'

> Does string 'NULL' affect indexing, this goes back to the concept i
>   mentioned above?

I dont think 'NULL' affects performance. You can cross check it via the stats which you get. See [here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/indexes-on-null-columns-123227.html):

> As far as an index is concerned, a NULL is treated like any other
>   value. (Yeah, I know NULL is really the absense of a value, but index
>   manager failed the basic relational concepts course ;-)
>
> Given your stats, you won't be able to create a unique index on the
>   columns since a unique undex will only allow one NULL. With a
>   non-unique index, all the NULLs will be gathered into a single index
>   key (with lots of associated RIDs).

Comment: Actually, depending on the platform and version of DB2, you may be able to have an `UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL`  index.  Which treats every NULL as a unique value.